# Application is "sleeping" when one phone gets locked, but not on another phone

Tags: android

I have two phones my application is running on. An LG G2 (Android 4.4.2) and a Wiko Lenny 2 (Android 5.1).

In my Android application I have a loop sending SMS, wait for 10 seconds, send the next SMS, etc.

On my LG G2, all the SMS are sent ; it may last for 15 minutes. But on my Wiko, I must interact with the phone (unlock it, ...) for the application to continue sending the SMS. It looks like the application is sleeping and then continues where it stopped once I "wake up" the phone.

Why is there a difference between the two phones? Is it something new in Android 5.x that the application sleeps when the phone sleeps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the manufacturer has modified the OS on the Wiko to restrict background processes (to reduce battery usage, Xiaomi does the same with MIUI, for example).

Do you receive notifications normally on the Wiko?

You might find some sort of pre-installed app on the phone where you can whitelist your app or disable the restriction of background processes.

Answer (score 2):

See here for additional information. It seems specific to Wiko phones:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155507/phone-is-killing-important-background-sync-processes-wiko-lenny-3-what-to-do